# Access configuration object from class method in rails gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I'm creating a gem that will abstract some rather bizarre api calls to a third party server and am exposing features as class methods (i.e. API::Connection.get_traveller).

I currently have a Configuration class in the same module which will be set up in a rails initializer. I was wondering how I can get the class methods to access the configuration object created in the initializer? Is there a rails config object I attach it to or something?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you post some code examples? your question is a bit cryptic.